# Tabulator : Field ID when importing from a javascript dataArray

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using Google script to create a webapp.

I've got data from my google GSheet and loaded it into an array, called 'data' using javascript.

Using Tabulator, I can display the data in a table by using the autoColumns feature.

However the Table header fields are listed as 0,1,2,3 even though the first record contains the actual fields names. (Email, Status, Last Login, etc)

When I try and create my own header names, it requires the filed name - field:"xxx"

So my question - how do i find that field name....

```js
columns:[
    {title:"Email", field:"**xxx**"},
]
```

I've used 0,1,2,3 - didn't work

Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 - didn't work

Not sure what else to try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the array of objects you are passing into the Tabulator ***data*** property

The ***field*** value for each column is the property name in the row data object

For example if your row data object is:

```
{name:"steve", age:23, driver:False},
```

Then the column definition for the name column would be:

```
{title:"Name", field:"name"},
```